# JQuery autcomplete not working in dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to apply jQuery AutoComplete for a textbox in a dialog box. Below is the code.

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++"
];

$("#status").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    appendTo: "#dialogId"
});
```

```
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="status" class="form-control form-control-sm col-8" id="status" />
```

In this approach, the autocomplete is not working. The autocomplete CSS and `autocomplete="off"/"on"` tags are not getting applied to the textbox.

If I try to apply it in the parent page, it is working as expected as below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-8 ui-autocomplete-input" id="auto" autocomplete="off">
```

Please help with what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the dialog is not visible when the autocomplete is instantiated, therefore the plugin doesn't know where on the screen to position the options dropdown.

To fix this, only instantiate the autocomplete control *after* the dialog is visible on the screen. As you're using jQueryUI you need to hook an event handler to the [`open`](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) event of the dialog and call `$("#status").autocomplete()` in there.